# Div overlap problem

Tags: html, resize, scroll, screen, overlap

I have a div on either side of my page that are meant to move closer together as the screen gets smaller, with nothing in between. The problem is that I can't get them to stop moving closer, when someone for instance has a small screen or the browser is resized. On too small of a screen the links and the information section start to intersect, which makes the site impossible to use.

I've tried using min-width, but it doesn't seem to do anything on any browser. I can't seem to find any viable alternate solutions. I'm fairly new at coding, so I'm hoping it's just something simple that I'm forgetting to do.

I'm using Firefox primarily. Thanks in advance for any and all assistance. =P

[THIS IS THE SITE](http://www.fixboxcomputers.com)

Answer (score 0):

Either you allow all elements to be redimensionable, or you just have to put the menu above the content adding `position:relative` and `z-index:1` (in that case don't forget to change links background to make them visible).

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about making things re-dimensionable, but that would be preferred. =P  I was doing some research on the subject, but can't seem to find a viable method of doing it within CSS. If CSS can't do it properly, I'll default to Java.